How do I use gym supermario v3 env as model input but use gym supermario v0 env in the screen?
I want to run gym-supermario-bros on my computer, but I train it on supermario v3 env, I want to see it in v0 version, is there a good way to use my trained agent in supermario v3 env but render v0 screen?
I tried to create two env: supermariobros v0, and supermariobros v3, and used the same seed to reset.
I use env_v3's state as the input of model and render env_v0's state to the screen.
picture of my attempt to achieve my goal.
But the two env's behavior is not the same.
In the end, I tried to render both env_v0's state and env_v3's and manipulate it by hand, I found that given the same action (for example, right), the env_v0 always go more fast and more far.
so the env_v3's state is always left behind and this error accumulates.
